# How to set String array from variable in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have the following piece of code:

```
String[] arr = [
            "Cat",
            "Dog",
            "Horse"
    ]

String payload = """
{
    "Data" : ${arr}
}
"""
```

My end goal is to obtain a payload as:

```
{"Data":["Cat", "Dog", "Horse"]}
```

But the result I get is:

```
{"Data":[Cat, Dog, Horse]}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had been doing it wrong and found the solution using the help of a friend:

```
String payload = """
{
    "Data" : ${JsonOutput.toJson(arr)}
}
"""
```

Comment: Don't _partially_ generate the JSON.  Generate the whole thing: `JsonOutput.toJson([Data: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]])`

Answer (score 0):

The groovy way would be simply

```
String[] arr = [
            "Cat",
            "Dog",
            "Horse"
    ]
String payload = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson( Data:arr )

assert '{"Data":["Cat","Dog","Horse"]}' == payload
```